# ie9 fallback for bootstrap carousel fade variation

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I used the pure css code from this post to make my carousels fade. As the question indicates, is there a way to make it fade in IE9 as well? Seems that normalizr doesn't quite do the this job for me, should it do it? I searched for transition fallbacks, didn't find any and i saw when i looked again at modernizr that it has it. I don't quite understand how the carousel works so i can close in on why exacly doesn't get a jquery replacement when i have IE9. How should i do this?

[Can the Twitter Bootstrap Carousel plugin fade in and out on slide transition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9526970/can-the-twitter-bootstrap-carousel-plugin-fade-in-and-out-on-slide-transition)

CSS

```
.carousel.fade {
    opacity: 1;
}

.carousel.fade .item {
    -moz-transition: opacity ease-in-out 1.5s;
    -o-transition: opacity ease-in-out 1.5s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity ease-in-out 1.5s;
    transition: opacity ease-in-out 1.5s;
    left: 0 !important;
    opacity: 0;
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    display: block !important;
    z-index: 100;
}

.carousel.fade .item:first-child {
    top: auto;
    position: relative;
}

.carousel.fade .item.active {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transition: opacity ease-in-out 1.5s;
    -o-transition: opacity ease-in-out 1.5s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity ease-in-out 1.5s;
    transition: opacity ease-in-out 1.5s;
    z-index: 200;
}
```

HTML

```
                  <div class="crsl-wrap">
                        <div id="shop-crsl-1" class="carousel slide carousel-fade shop-crsl hidden-xs" data-ride="carousel">

                            <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                            <div class="carousel-inner">
                                <div class="item active">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                                            <div class="shop-col-item">
                                                <div class="photo">
                                                    <img src="images/sc/shop-crsl-1.png" class="img-responsive" alt="a">
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="info">
                                                    <div>
                                                        <div class="price">
                                                            <h5>Casual Suit</h5>
                                                            <h5 class="main-text-color">$199.99</h5>
                                                        </div>

                                                        <div class="rating">
                                                            <i class="main-text-color fa fa-star"></i>
                                                            <i class="main-text-color fa fa-star"></i>
                                                            <i class="main-text-color fa fa-star"></i>
                                                            <i class="main-text-color fa fa-star"></i>
                                                            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>

                                                    <div class="btns clear-left">
                                                        <p class="btn-add"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i><a href="#">Add to cart</a></p>
                                                        <p class="btn-details"><i class="fa fa-list"></i><a href="#">More details</a></p>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                                            <div class="shop-col-item">
                                                <div class="photo">
                                                    <img src="images/sc/shop-crsl-2.png" class="img-responsive" alt="a">
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="info">
                                                    <div>
                                                        <div class="price">
                                                            <h5>Night Suit</h5>
                                                            <h5 class="main-text-color">$249.99</h5>
                                                        </div>

                                                        <div class="rating">

                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>

                                                    <div class="btns clear-left">
                                                        <p class="btn-add"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i><a href="#">Add to cart</a></p>
                                                        <p class="btn-details"><i class="fa fa-list"></i><a href="#">More details</a></p>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                                            <div class="shop-col-item">
                                                <div class="photo">
                                                    <img src="images/sc/shop-crsl-3.png" class="img-responsive" alt="a">
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="info">
                                                    <div>
                                                        <div class="price">
                                                            <h5>Elegant Suit</h5>
                                                            <h5 class="main-text-color">$149.99</h5>
                                                        </div>

                                                        <div class="rating">
                                                            <i class="main-text-color fa fa-star"></i>
                                                            <i class="main-text-color fa fa-star"></i>
                                                            <i class="main-text-color fa fa-star"></i>
                                                            <i class="main-text-color fa fa-star"></i>
                                                            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>

                                                    <div class="btns clear-left">
                                                        <p class="btn-add"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i><a href="#">Add to cart</a></p>
                                                        <p class="btn-details"><i class="fa fa-list"></i><a href="#">More details</a></p>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="item">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                                            <div class="shop-col-item">
                                                <div class="photo">
                                                    <img src="images/sc/shop-crsl-1.png" class="img-responsive" alt="a">
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="info">
                                                    <div>
                                                        <div class="price">
                                                            <h5>Super-Casual Suit</h5>
                                                            <h5 class="main-text-color">$199.99</h5>
                                                        </div>

                                                        <div class="rating">
                                                            <i class="main-text-color fa fa-star"></i>
                                                            <i class="main-text-color fa fa-star"></i>
                                                            <i class="main-text-color fa fa-star"></i>
                                                            <i class="main-text-color fa fa-star"></i>
                                                            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>

                                                    <div class="btns clear-left">
                                                        <p class="btn-add"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i><a href="#">Add to cart</a></p>
                                                        <p class="btn-details"><i class="fa fa-list"></i><a href="#">More details</a></p>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                                            <div class="shop-col-item">
                                                <div class="photo">
                                                    <img src="images/sc/shop-crsl-2.png" class="img-responsive" alt="a">
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="info">
                                                    <div>
                                                        <div class="price">
                                                            <h5>Super-Night Suit</h5>
                                                            <h5 class="main-text-color">$249.99</h5>
                                                        </div>

                                                        <div class="rating">

                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>

                                                    <div class="btns clear-left">
                                                        <p class="btn-add"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i><a href="#">Add to cart</a></p>
                                                        <p class="btn-details"><i class="fa fa-list"></i><a href="#">More details</a></p>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                                            <div class="shop-col-item">
                                                <div class="photo">
                                                    <img src="images/sc/shop-crsl-3.png" class="img-responsive" alt="a">
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="info">
                                                    <div>
                                                        <div class="price">
                                                            <h5>Super-Elegant Suit</h5>
                                                            <h5 class="main-text-color">$149.99</h5>
                                                        </div>

                                                        <div class="rating">
                                                            <i class="main-text-color fa fa-star"></i>
                                                            <i class="main-text-color fa fa-star"></i>
                                                            <i class="main-text-color fa fa-star"></i>
                                                            <i class="main-text-color fa fa-star"></i>
                                                            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>

                                                    <div class="btns clear-left">
                                                        <p class="btn-add"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i><a href="#">Add to cart</a></p>
                                                        <p class="btn-details"><i class="fa fa-list"></i><a href="#">More details</a></p>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <!-- Controls -->
                        <div class="controls">
                            <a class="left fa fa-chevron-left" href="#shop-crsl-1" data-slide="prev"> </a>
                            <a class="right fa fa-chevron-right" href="#shop-crsl-1" data-slide="next"> </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`IE9` not supports `transition` Use [fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadein) and [fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout) like,

```
$(function(){
   $('.item').fadeIn(1500);
   $('.active').fadeOut(1500);
});
```

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6544162/imitate-css3-transition-in-ie) for more details.